# How to upgrade my mac book pro to java 7.0?

Tags: java, macos

I'm trying to upgrade to java 7 on my mac book pro
I have os x 10.9.5 running on it.
I went to the site
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_java_update.xml
Which said there would be a icon for java in system preference.  I do not have this icon and do not know how to call up the java control panel.

Comment: try clicking on the settings. You should have an icon next to flash in the bottom corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp) and click to check your Java version and you should get a popup asking if you want to install Java 7 from Oracle. Approve the install to do the installation. You'll also get java icon in system preferences after this. [Ref](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1599188)